# How do computers know the capacities of drives connected to them?

Tags: hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, storage, usb-storage

Plugging my 32GB USB drive into my computer, how does the computer know that it is a 32GB drive? Where is that information stored, and how is it retrieved?

Comment: When you plug any USB device the OS asks "what are you?" and the devices replies and is dealt by the OS accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do computers know the capacities of drives connected to them?

Early PC hard disk drives (e.g. ST506, MFM, RLL) required user-supplied parameters for the drive geometry (i.e. number of sectors per track, number of R/W heads, and number of cylinders) for [CHS addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector).  Of course (IBM) PCs assumed/defined a sector size of 512 bytes.
These parameters were typically stored in the BIOS of the PC.

IDE drives introduced the ATA command set, which included an `Identify Device` command (using command code 0xEC), which reported the drive geometry and other information.
By version 3 of ATAPI, the response to this command included the `total number of user addressable sectors`.  (I don't have any earlier version of the ATAPI specification, so I'm not sure exactly what was in the response pre-ATA-3.)
Using the total number of sectors and the sector size, the total capacity of the drive is easily calculated.
Since modern versions of ATA (e.g. SATA drives with zone bit recording) no longer support CHS addressing, the drive geometry is irrelevant (and not even constant because of [zone bit recording](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_bit_recording)).

USB flash drives simply use the USB as a transport protocol, and implement the ATA command set just like HDDS and SSDs.  So the capacity of USB flash drives (and SATA HDDs/SSDs) can easily be obtained by interrogating the drive by using the ATA `Identify Device` command.

SD cards have a proprietary command protocol for use over its interface.  The card's capacity, speed capabilities, and other information is reported as a response over its command line (and not through the card's data interface).

---

Operating systems primarily provide user access to mass storage devices such as HDDs and SSDs as filesystems.
By PC conventions, the drive must be partitioned, and a filesystem must exist in a partition of the drive.  Note that floppies and optionally USB flash drives are not partitioned.
The salient drive parameters (i.e. the start and end sector/LBA addresses) of the partitions are retrieved from the partition table (located in the MBR or GPT sector(s)).

Answer (score 2):

The OS is more or less entirely dependent on the drive for communicating the drive capacity.

This fact is taken advantage of...

- for good purposes in most common SSDs where significant portions of storage space are retained for caching and as spare storage for when the drive begins to age
- and for bad purposes when cheap USB drives claim they are much larger than they actually are, even fooling the OS into writing more data than they are capable of retaining

Drives of all types contain small amounts of non-volatile memory which contains this information on it and which reports to the OS on connection.

Answer (score 2):

PCs do not control the drive directly, they issue commands to a host adapter or controller on a bus.  For modern (since at least late 80's/early 90's) drives, the adapter/controller forwards these commands to a CPU on the drive running firmware.  Standardized busses and their corresponding command schemes include ATA, AHCI, SCSI, SAS.

Parameters specific to the drive, such as capacity, are part of or discoverable by that firmware, and specific commands make the firmware return that info instead of doing a read/write of data.

For example: The ATA-1 standard (very old) describes the "Identify Drive" command which returns the CHS values of the drive, from which the capacity can be determined.  So this would be the first command an OS sends to the drive before doing any read/write operations.

I don't think drives before ATA, like MFM or RLL drives, had intelligent firmware (other than for formatting) - for these early 80's systems you had to know the "Drive Type" - which was just a well-known capacity, or directly set a custom capacity in the BIOS.

With USB, it's the same principle - there are commands sent over USB that talk to a controller that get info instead of reading/writing data.